# composition series of module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $K$ be a field, and consider the $2-$module $\displaystyle{ (K^5 , \phi , \psi)}$, where $\phi $ and $\psi$ are the $K-linear$ maps given by

$\phi = \left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
c_0 &  &  &  &  \\
 & c_0 &  &  &  \\
 &  & c_1 \\
 & & & c_2  &\\
 & & & & c_3\end{array} \right)$
and $\psi= \left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 &  & 0 \\
 & & & 0  &\\
 & & & & 0\end{array} \right)$

with $c_0 ,c_1,c_2,c_3 \in K $ pairwise distinct.

How can we find all the composition series of such a module?

Is the first time I see such a problem, and although I searched I didn't manage to find something similar.

Any help would be really appreciated.

**Edit:**

**Definition of module:** Let $V$ be a $K-$vector space. Then a $J-$module $V$ is a pair of the form $(V,\phi_j)_{j \in J}$ where $\phi_j : V \to V$ are $K-$linear maps.

Comment: I don't think I understand your notation. Which part is a module over what?

Comment: I have edit my post, please check it and if it is something confusing let me know. Thank you.

Comment: These are a (form of) modules over the free algebra on two generators.

Comment: So in that definition, $J$ can be just any set? What does it mean for something to be a submodule then? That all those maps preserve it?

Comment: Yes. A submodule $U$ of $V$ is a subspace such that for every $\phi_j$ we have $\phi_j (u) \in U $ for every $u \in U$.

Comment: So I guess part of my confusion is that you call your module $2$-dimensional, but I suppose you mean a $\{1,2\}$-module?

Comment: That was a typo! It should be only $2-$module. I fix immediately. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Can you find the socle of the module?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: No, I can't find the simple submodules to take their sum, which gives the socle...I have totally stuck, I can't think anything on how to procceed...

Comment: Find a basis in which $\psi$ is taken to its Jordan canonical form, find its invariant subspaces, and then see which of them are invariant also fo $\phi$.

Comment: Dear MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, I would really appreciate If you could write a more complete answer. I know, that giving hints is better because makes you think on your own, but at this particular moment I can't think at all...

Comment: Well, come back to the problem in a day or two :-) I'll add an answer later.

Comment: O.k thank you! In the midtime I will try again...